# angular change ng-model dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have this i a directive:

```
 if (scope.quesProp.required) {
            scope.required = '!someSelected(choices.selectedStuff)';
        } else {
            scope.required = false;
        }
```

and this in the template:

```
< some input val....
ng-required= 'required'
 ..>
```

I want it to change between false and !someSelected(choices.selectedStuff),
it's not working if i do the above, and everything works great if in the template i change it back to this:

```
ng-required='!someSelected(choices.selectedStuff)'
```

Comment: Why not use a scope-function? e.g.: `ng-required="isFieldRequired()"`? And let that function return true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
< some input val....
ng-required= cond && !someSelected(choices.selectedStuff)
 ..>
```

If cond has the value false, the rest condition will be ignored,
and if the cond is true, the next condition will be evaluated.

You can change the cond variable from your controller.

```
//var cond= true/false;
```